# tcl curl post request with headers

Tags: curl, tcl

I am trying to use [tclcurl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2638) to interact with a web service. However, I am having trouble to build a post request with headers (equivalent to `-H` in command line).
I cannot provide sample code because the endpoint I am using is not public.

I am doing it this way:

```
set curlHandle [curl::init]
$curlHandle configure -url $url -bodyvar html -post 1 -postfields $data -header "header1: value1" -header "header2: value2"
```

And it is complaining `-header` is not recognized as option and it should be in a list of options and header is among those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the wiki page that you linked to, I see that the way you're supposed to provide custom headers is (probably) a bit different. I'd guess that you're supposed to provide a list to the `-httpheader` option, something like this:

```
set curlHandle [curl::init]
set headers [list "header1: value1" "header2: value2"]
$curlHandle configure -url $url -bodyvar html -post 1 -postfields $data -httpheader $headers
```

Admittedly this is only on the basis of an example using the `curl::transfer` command and I haven't tested it, but I'd guess that your method will work like this too. Virtually all Tcl packages tend to be consistent that sort of way.

---

I've never needed `curl` for the web service calls I've done with Tcl; the standard Tcl `http` package is pretty capable despite being pure Tcl code…